# чпу для ссылки с якорем

Tags: php, .htaccess, apache

Настраиваю чпу для сайта первый раз и столкнулся с ситуацией - есть у меня якорь на главной странице и я хочу что бы нажимая на кнопку ГЛАВНАЯ(в менюбар) или вводя в адресную строку(www.mysite/main) у меня переходило сразу к месту где у меня установлен якорь. Делаю я это через .htaccess, **RewriteRule ^main$ index.php#Main [NC,L]**. На данный момент у меня происходит загрузка просто index.php без перехода к якорю.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<s>Это будет работать только с дополнительным редиректом</s>. Это в принципе невозможно сделать в таком варианте.
Только на другой адрес, типа  **/truerealmain#main**
То есть, на мой вкус, овчинка выделки не стоит.

Вместо этих выкрутасов я настоятельно порекомендую сделать дезигн попроще. Так, чтобы пользователь видел полезный контент сразу, без якорей и редиректов.